# How to simplify if $a > 0$ and $\cos(a) < 0$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, hyperbolic-functions

$$\sqrt{\cos (a)} \sinh \left(\ln (2) a^{\frac{1}{2} \left(e^{-ia }+e^{ia}\right)}\right)+\sqrt{\cos (a)} \cosh \left(\ln (2)
   a^{\frac{1}{2} \left(e^{-ia }+e^{ia }\right)}\right)=$$

Comment: It is better if you add your own idea in the question.

Comment: I believe the context for this question is that the above expression was the "simplification" of $2^{a^{\cos a}} \sqrt{\cos a}$ offered by Sonnhard Graubner on a now-closed/deleted question (note to OP: take any Dr. Sonnhard Graubner answer with a pinch of salt). So now we have all three answers just pointing back to the original expression.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:** $\frac12 (e^{ia}+e^{-ia})=\cos a$

**Hint 2:** $\cosh x+\sinh x=e^x$

**Hint 3:** $e^{\log x}=x$

Comment: In Hint 1 you probably mean $e^{ia} + e^{-ia}$ and not $e^a + e^{-a}$.

Comment: @ericwong Good catch.  Edit complete.  Thank you, much appreciative.

Comment: @Dr.MV how do you justify Hint 1? whats the "theory" & how exactly does it incorporate with the rest of the expression?

Comment: @Antares Check Euler's identity as a reference. The term $\frac12 (e^{ia}+e^{-ia}$ appears twice in exponents.

Answer (score 0):

With $\log(a)$ as the natural logarithm $\ln(a)$ gives us:

$$\sqrt{\cos (a)} \sinh \left(\ln (2) a^{\frac{1}{2} \left(e^{-ia }+e^{ia}\right)}\right)+\sqrt{\cos (a)} \cosh \left(\ln (2)
   a^{\frac{1}{2} \left(e^{-ia }+e^{ia }\right)}\right)=$$

$$\sqrt{\cos (a)} \sinh \left(\ln (2) a^{\cos(a)}\right)+\sqrt{\cos (a)} \cosh \left(\ln (2) a^{\cos(a)}\right)=$$

Evaluates to:

$$2^{a^{\cos(a)}}\sqrt{\cos(a)}$$

Comment: can you move $2^{a^{\cos(a)}}$ to inside the radical sign and put ${\cos(a)}$ on the outside?

Comment: ...or technically remove the cos(a) from $2^{a^{\cos(a)}}$

Comment: No that's not possible!

Comment: so if $a > 0$ & $cos(a) < 0$ is there "a way" to simplify any further using $pi$ or some trigonometric redux rule...?  On $2^{a^{\cos(a)}}\sqrt{\cos(a)}$