# Simplification of $\sin(\pi^x)$ , with $x$ being a positive irrational number

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, hypergeometric-function

[How to simplify if $a > 0$ and $\cos(a) < 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273443/how-to-simplify-if-a-0-and-cosa-0)

Was a previous post. Correction, it was suppose to be if a > 0 & cos(a) > 0.

An answer was given. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1274372/575423

Does this change the solution given?, if so how, exactly how? (Including the "evaluates to" part!)

Simplification of sin(pi^x) , with x being a positive irrational number

sin(pi^x) ----> ((y)) has to be a negative irrational.

Regarding bounds: x is -2pi < x < 2pi.

The range of cos(a) and (a) is 0 < a < 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to simplify $\sin(\pi^x)$ where $x$ is a positive irrational number, the answer is that in general there is no such simplification.

Comment: x is no greater than 2pi. The range of cos(a) and (a) is 0<a<2.

Comment: Range doesn't matter. Robert's answer still applies.

Comment: is https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1274372/575423 correct?

Comment: Isn't that a totally different question, 575423? What does it have to do with $\sin\pi^x$?

Comment: yes it was something I was trying to figure out about 2 years ago... and I needed insight on it.

Comment: Then it has no business being a comment on Robert's answer. So, are you happy with Robert's answer?

Comment: no ...not necessarily.

Comment: I just don't see how I asked a question 2 years ago and it gets an answer ... hyperbolic geometry to have that "render" to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1274372/575423 but there is no way to simplify said answer in the realm of hyperbolic geometry!

Comment: The answer you got to that question two years ago is the answer to that question. There is no way to simplify that answer, in the realm of hyperbolic geometry or any other realm. And it doesn't matter what the range of $a$ is, nor whether $\cos a$ is positive, negative, or zero. The answer you got two years ago is the answer. Why do you think otherwise? Do you understand how that answer was obtained?

Comment: not really I would appreciate how to build my algebra 2/pre calc skills to such level of hyperbolic geometry

Comment: Then maybe *that* is the question you should be posting. (But there is no *hyperbolic geometry* whatsoever in that question or in the answers – I'm not sure you know what mathematicians mean by *hyperbolic geometry*.)

Comment: I honestly don't. I watch youtube videos for answers ,but to no avail...